# MS access running SQL doesn't insert data, no error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I want to add data to this table from a form.

[image]

I have Combo box for the Job and Team ID's that look up data from their respective tables.

```
Private Sub save_new_Click()
On Error GoTo save_new_Click_Err

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Employee (Name,ATUUID,Job ID,Team ID,Start Date, Comments) " & _
     " VALUES(" & Me.Employye_Name & ", " & Me.ATTUID & ", " & Me.cboFunc & ", " & _
     Me.cboTeam & ", " & Me.Start_Date & ", " & Me.Comments & ")"
     Debug.Print strSQL
    With CurrentDb
        .Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError
        Debug.Print .RecordsAffected
    End With
```

Here is the resulting SQL string:

```
 INSERT INTO Employee (Name,ATUUID,Job ID,Team ID,Start Date, Comments)  VALUES(asd, asd, 1, 2, 7/10/2015, asdasd)
```

Debug.Print .RecordsAffected

Prints 0

Comment: You need to delimit your strings with `"` (or maybe it is `'` --- can't remember for access.)

Comment: No Error? - not surprising: remove `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), which is why your query is failing. it's totally invalid. `7/10/2015` is mathematical DIVISION, not a date. `asdasd` is a field name, not a string, blah blah blah

Comment: @AlexK.: gotta love languages that give you the power to say "I've just destroyed the entire universe, oh well, let's just pretend that didn't happen"

Comment: The first step in debugging it for me would be to run the query on the SQL Server using Management Studio,  and see if it actually works;  as others have said I suspect it won't.  If it does... then run activity monitor on the server while running your code, and see what, if anything, happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@AlexK. explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457924/ms-access-running-sql-doesnt-insert-data-no-error/31459111#comment50882828_31457924), the reason you're not seeing errors is because `On Error Resume Next` hides errors. When you use that, you're telling Access *"ignore any error --- don't even mention it --- and continue at the next line."*

But the `INSERT` statement that code builds will definitely trigger an error.  You can confirm that fact if you copy the output of `Debug.Print strSQL` from the Immediate window, create a new query in the query designer, switch the query to SQL View, paste in the statement text and try to run it.

When you have a field name which includes a space, you must enclose it in square brackets so the db engine recognizes it as one identifier instead of two.  I would also bracket *Name* because it's a reserved word, but I doubt it actually contributes to the problem here:

```vb
"INSERT INTO Employee ([Name], ATUUID, [Job ID], [Team ID], [Start Date], Comments)"
```

Beyond that, I suggest you use a temporary `QueryDef` based on a parameter query, supply the parameter values, and `Execute` it.

```vb
'On Error Resume Next '<-- leave this disabled, AT LEAST while debugging!
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO Employee ([Name], ATUUID, [Job ID], [Team ID], [Start Date], Comments)" & vbCrLf & _
    "VALUES (pName, pATUUID, pJobID, pTeamID, pStartDate, pComments);"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)
With qdf
    .Parameters("pName").Value = Me.Employye_Name.Value
    .Parameters("pATUUID").Value = Me.ATTUID.Value
    .Parameters("pJobID").Value = Me.cboFunc.Value
    .Parameters("pTeamID").Value = Me.cboTeam.Value
    .Parameters("pStartDate").Value = Me.Start_Date.Value
    .Parameters("pComments").Value = Me.Comments.Value
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
Debug.Print db.RecordsAffected
```

Comment: thanks this solved the issue, I also messed up on ATUUID which is ATTUID :D