# ACCESS 365 and INSERT INTO not inserting data from FORM

Tags: sql, insert, sql-insert

I am updating a small medical database. So far all new products have been added manually / directly to a Products- table. I am creating a form to do that.
Even it is in a way very simple to do, I am facing up a problem that data is inserted correctly only if all fields have something typed in form, if any of the input boxes are left empty no new records are made.
Additionally a simple check for minimum fields is not working. It will step thru all controls correctly but does not stop even a field is left empty and its Tag has *-sign in it.
Insert into includes all fields which a defined in that table there is not any extra field in table except first field is autonumbered ID field. No need to type something in every field each time.
Pr

```
Private Function CheckAllFields() As Boolean
  Dim Ctrl As Control
  CheckAllFields = False
  'Go through the controls in Form
  'If control has tag (*) and it null (no value) then show alert
  For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
  MsgBox Ctrl.Name
     If Ctrl.Tag = "*" And IsNull(Ctrl) Then
                Dim FieldName As String
                FieldName = Ctrl.Name
                'Show notification if field was not filled and move focus to that field
                MsgBox "A required Field has not been filled."
                Ctrl.SetFocus
        CheckAllFields = True
        Exit For
     End If
  Next Ctrl
  MsgBox "Check fileds done"
End Function

Private Sub AddProduct_Click()
    
    Dim strSQL As String

    'SQL to insert Product
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Products([Product name],[Product description],[Finnish name],[Finnish description],[Matrix2012], " & _
        "[Additional Info], [Unit], [Licence],[Remarks],Narcotic,[Asset], " & _
        "[ATC], [Cathegory], [EIC code], [EIC name])" & _
        " VALUES ('" & Me.txtProductName & "','" & Me.txtProductDesc & "','" & Me.txtFinnishName & "','" & Me.txtFinnishDesc & "','" & Me.ComboMatrix & "'," & _
        "'" & Me.txtAdditionalInfo & "','" & Me.ComboUnit & "','" & Me.CheckLicense & "'," & _
        "'" & Me.txtRemarks & "','" & Me.CheckNarcotic & "','" & Me.CheckAsset & "'," & _
        "'" & Me.txtATC & "','" & Me.txtCathegory & "','" & Me.txtEICcode & "','" & Me.txtEICName & "')"
        
''  MsgBox strSQL

    'Check the all fields have valid format
    
    If CheckAllFields = False Then
        'Execute SQL in database - insert new batch
'         MsgBox "Step into Check all fields"
         
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
        MsgBox "A new product inserted !"
        
    End If
```

Here is a debug output of my insert into command:

[Debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt7Rs.png)

Here is another output debug, now the new product is inserted correctly.

[Correctly working version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX3L8.png)

Comment: Two points - firstly, building a SQL statement like that is very prone to SQL injection.  You should be using a parameterised query instead (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) - only a handful of extra lines of code, but offers protection against the basic SQL injection you are already potentially opening up.

Comment: Secondly, I'm assuming that this code is VBA or VB (you haven't specified exactly what you're creating this application in).  You are checking "IsNull()" on your control, and further assuming that the "default" property will be inferred (eg. the text of a text-box, the checked value of a check-box), you won't get a "Null" value just because the text-box is empty, or the check-box is unchecked.  If a text-box is empty, the value will be an empty string ("") - if a check-box is unchecked, the value will be False.  So your IsNull() call is never likely to return True.

Comment: That is simply a Access Form where VBA is run by clicking a button to save data.

Comment: OK, I assumed it would be something similar to that.  Thus my suggestion about your use if IsNull(), in my previous comment, should get you one step along the way

Comment: I quickly tested by using IsEmpty, but it did not make any difference. If Ctrl.Tag = "*" And IsEmpty(Ctrl) Then.  This is pretty confusing as it worked in another form with similar fileds. Must be some sort of referencing issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. As Craig pointed this way of incuding parameters is prone to fail.

Here is good way to solve this. Did not believe it but after I tried it worked ultimate.
[MS access running SQL doesn't insert data, no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457924/ms-access-running-sql-doesnt-insert-data-no-error/67379884#67379884)

```
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Products([Product name],[Product description],[Finnish name],[Finnish description],[Matrix2012], " & _
        "[Additional Info], [Unit], [Licence],[Remarks],Narcotic,[Asset], " & _
        "[ATC], [Cathegory], [EIC code], [EIC name])" & _
        " VALUES (ptxtProductName, ptxtProductDesc,ptxtFinnishName,ptxtFinnishDesc,pComboMatrix, ptxtAdditionalInfo,pComboUnit, pCheckLicense, ptxtRemarks, pCheckNarcotic, pCheckAsset, ptxtATC, ptxtCathegory, ptxtEICCode, ptxtEICName);"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)
With qdf
    .Parameters("ptxtProductName").Value = Me.txtProductName.Value
    .Parameters("ptxtProductDesc").Value = Me.txtProductDesc.Value
    .Parameters("ptxtFinnishName").Value = Me.txtFinnishName.Value
    .Parameters("ptxtFinnishDesc").Value = Me.txtFinnishDesc.Value
    .Parameters("pComboMatrix").Value = Me.ComboMatrix.Value
    .Parameters("ptxtAdditionalInfo").Value = Me.txtAdditionalInfo.Value
    .Parameters("pComboUnit").Value = Me.ComboUnit.Value
    .Parameters("pCheckLicense").Value = Me.CheckLicense.Value
    .Parameters("ptxtRemarks").Value = Me.txtRemarks.Value
    .Parameters("pCheckNarcotic").Value = Me.CheckNarcotic.Value
    .Parameters("pCheckAsset").Value = Me.CheckAsset.Value
    .Parameters("ptxtATC").Value = Me.txtATC.Value
    .Parameters("ptxtCathegory").Value = Me.txtCathegory.Value
    .Parameters("ptxtEICCode").Value = Me.txtEICcode.Value
    .Parameters("ptxtEICName").Value = Me.txtEICName.Value
    
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
Debug.Print db.RecordsAffected
```

That check for empty fields is mystery, it works in another form so it has to be some sort of reference problem. Anyway to keep things simple this works perfectly:

```
If txtProductName.Value = "" Or ComboMatrix.Value = "" Or ComboUnit.Value = "" Then
   'Show notification if field was not filled and move focus to that field
                MsgBox "A required Field has not been filled."
```